# Application to scrape the questions, answers and comments I posted on Quora

Tags: data-liberation, scraping, quora

Quora is notorious for offering no way to retrieve the questions, answers and comments a user posted on Quora.

I'm looking for a program, script, browser plugin or web-service that can

- scrape the questions, answers and comments I posted on Quora (or at least one of those three categories to begin with)

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7 if OS-dependent
- minimize the number of removals